# I do not want my textView can be selected, but can detect link. Can UITextView selectable=NO and dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll same time?

Tags: ios, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I do not want my `textView` can be selected, but can detect link and link can be touched.

```
textView.selectable=NO
textView.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll
```

But when `selectable=NO`, it can not detect link.

Comment: You can try some solution from this article. It was written by Objective-C but i think you can convert to Swift easily:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690164/uitextview-with-clickable-links-but-no-text-highlighting

Comment: Can't you just disable editable?

Comment: tks, but i can not get rid of the magnify glass